# execute sql query on button click

Tags: sql, button, click, exec

nw_check.php

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>

 <html>
 <body>
    <form method="POST" action="nw_check_exec.php">
        <input type="button" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

nw_check_exec.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['nw_update'])){
        echo("You clicked button one!");
        //and then execute a sql query here
    }
    else {
    echo" dhur";
    }
?>
```

but for some reason the echo in the nw_check_exec.php is not being executed. please could you help.

Comment: Is *either* echo being executed in `nw_check_exec.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because the input type is a "button" and should be a submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
```